# Invalid Argument - Interfaces inherited, as works, implicit casting does not. What gives?

Tags: c#, linq, interface

I have a function that has a signature of

```
Update(IEnumberable<INotifyPropertyChanging> things)
```

and a class

```
doohickey : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanging{}
```

When I try to do

```
List<doohickey> doohickeys = new List<doohickey>();
Update(doohickeys);
```

An exception gets thrown stating:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<doohickey>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging>'
```

**What gives?  Doohickey inherits the INotifyPropertyChanging interface and List inherits the IEnumerable interface!  How come simply passing the object and expecting it to get cast down doesn't?**

*I've included the references to INotifyPropertyChanging to signify that doohickey is actually a linq-to-sql class; in case that bit of context matters.*

Comment: I think it has to do with covariance/contravariance. Are you using C# 4? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: do you have _exception_ or _compile error_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work because there is no implicit conversion between `List<doohickey>` and `IEnumerable<NotifyPropertyChanging>`. You need to call:

```
Update(doohickeys.Cast<INotifyPropertyChanging>());
```

The reason behind this is type safety. In C#4, co-/contravariance was added to the language, which generally helps making these type of conversions valid. There are some limitations though, since the type involved needs to be declared co-/contravariant, and it only applies to interfaces and delegates.

The reason why you can't implicitly convert `List<T>` to `List<TBase>` is, that it would make this code valid:

```
List<T> values = new List<T>();
// add some values...
List<TBase> bases = values;
bases.Add(new TBase());  // Woops. We broke type safety by adding a TBase to a list of T's
```

Now, if you tried to do this when `values` was of type `IEnumerable<T>`, it would be valid in C#4. This is because you can only *get values out* of `IEnumerable<T>`, so we don't need to worry about lesser types being added. Therefore `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, and is declared as:

```
IEnumerable<out T>
```

Where `out` means "covariant". (The keywords is actually the best way to remember which way values may go in a variant type.

Co-/contravariance is a rather large subject, [but this article does a good job of explaining the most important parts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx). And if you want to learn more, Eric Lippert has an [11-part blog post series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) about the feature. Eric is one of the language designers.

Comment: For some reason I thought that casting down worked but casting up did not.  It seems the whole idea of "coding against an interface" hinged upon that idea in my mind.  While the fix doesn't seem too obtuse it still doesn't seem ideal.  I now need this .Cast<TBase>() stuff hanging off of my stuff adding mental cruft to my code.

Oddly enough this seemed to fix my issue however it flushed out another one where I was doing evil, wicked, ugly things with System.Reflection.

Thank you for the extremely valuable information!